# How do i fix SQLException when performing query on database?

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite

Im a noob to android and I am trying to run a query on my database to return a single string value from my table.  I have done this successfully in one query by selecting my row id using a long.  Shown here:

```
public String getHotness(long l) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{  KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String hotness = c.getString(2);
        return hotness;
    }
    c.close();
    return null;
}
```

But now i have to query another table using a string, but when i execute this query i get a SQLException.

```
public String getSingleQty(String aCoin) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE};     
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + aCoin, null, null, null, null); //<--this causes exception
    String result = "";

    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        result= c.getString(2);
        c.close();
        return result;
    }
    c.close();
    return null;
```

I don't understand why this is occurring.  I used the same format for both tables.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And whats the Exception??? Put Stacktrace of it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since aCoin is being passed as a string to the query, it has to be wrapped by apostrophes. Corrected fragment of code:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='" + aCoin + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

or (if the syntax suit you better) try it that way:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] {aCoin}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: oba rozwiązania są poprawne, kwestia składni (kto jaką woli)

Comment: problem by sie pojawił jak by w zmiennej aCoin był apostrof `'` :)

Comment: The `KEY_NAME + "=?"` syntax is safer, for example, it won't cause problems if `aCoin` happens to contain an apostrophe itself.  (which I think is what Selvin was saying)

Comment: yes, over all is better to use parameters not only on Android and not only because you can face problem with escaping special chars but also because possibility of SQL injections (on Android there is no problem coz you will eventually lost only local data but on web servers ...)